# Extract financial year from dates

Tags: r

I've several variables which i'm looking to organise by financial year (1 April to 31 March).

```
library(lubridate)
StartDate <- ymd(c("2017-03-26", "2018-07-04", "2019-02-23", "2010-10-31", "1989-06-30"))
```

I have been able to extract the year and quarter from these dates, specifiying the fiscal start as month 4, using lubridates quarter function. But i want the financial year variable to be in the format of 2017/18, 2018/19, etc.

I also found the date2fy function, which works:

```
date2fy(StartDate)
```

but it's default is the austrailian financial year running from 1 July to 30 June and can't figure out how to change it to start from 1 April.

I've written the below and it works, but is there any better/shorter method of doing it?

```
DEP$Start_Fin_Year <- as.numeric(format(DEP$StartDate, "%Y")) - (format(DEP$StartDate, "%m") <= "03")
library(stringr)
DEP$Start_Fin_Year2 <- str_sub(DEP$Start_Fin_Year,start=-2)
DEP$Start_Fin_Year2 <- as.numeric(DEP$Start_Fin_Year2)
DEP$Start_Fin_Year3 <- (DEP$Start_Fin_Year2 + 1)
DEP$Start_Fin_Year4 <- paste0(DEP$Start_Fin_Year, "/", DEP$Start_Fin_Year3)
```

Comment: This is the same method as yours, but since you're already using `lubridate` you can save a some characters by using lubridate funs `yr <- year(StartDate) - (month(StartDate) <= 3);
paste(yr, (yr + 1) %% 1e3, sep = '/')`

Answer (score 0):

```
tibble::tibble(StartDate = StartDate) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(finstart = ymd(paste0(year(StartDate), "-04-01")),
                finyear = ifelse(StartDate >= finstart, year(finstart) + 1, year(finstart)))
```